# Javascript: Rounding down Date() objects

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to write a function in javascript that will take a `Date` object and round it down based on the specified time period.

Lets assume the Date object is `1/29/18 1:14:08 PM` and the selected rounding period is `60 (one minute)`. The date would then become `1/29/18 1:14 PM`. Likewise, if the rounding period is `3600 (one hour)`, the date would become `1/29/18 1:00 PM`.

I'd also like to be able to specify divisible time periods, like 3 minutes (0, 3, 6, 9 ... 57, 60), which is why I'm doing it in such a roundabout way.

I have tried the following:

```
roundTimePeriod(date, granularity) {
    var adjustedDate = new Date(date);
    var seconds = adjustedDate.getTime() / 1000; //Get seconds since 1/1/1970
    seconds = seconds - (seconds % granularity);
    adjustedDate.setSeconds(seconds);

    return adjustedDate;
}
```

The problem with this is that when `setSeconds()` is called, it ends up adding those seconds to the current time instead of setting the total seconds.

Changing `setSeconds` to `setTime` and removing the `getTime() / 1000` division isn't as far off, but it still isn't correct.

Ideally, I would like this to also be able to round by week, so if 1/29 is a Monday, it would change the time to 12:00 AM on the Sunday of that week.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: off the top of my head ... `adjustedDate.setSeconds(adjustedDate.getSeconds() - (seconds % granularity));` (remove the preceding line)

Comment: I'd go for `if (granularity == 60) date.setSeconds(0) else if (granularity == 3600) date.setMinutes(0, 0) else if (granularity == …) date.setHours(0, 0, 0) else { date.setDay(0); date.setHours(0, 0, 0); }`. Anything else is pretty much arbitrary anyway.

Comment: `var m = (Math.round(seconds/60) * 60) % 60;` easiest way

Comment: If you want to round down to the minute, just set the seconds and milliseconds to zero: `adjustedDate.setSeconds(0,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

To round down to a specific unit like minute, hour, day, etc. just zero the following sub units. It takes a little more effort for week, but similar algorithm for month, year, etc.

```js
function roundTimePeriod(date, granularity) {
  switch (granularity) {
    case 'second' :
      date.setMilliseconds(0);
      break;
    case 'minute' :
      date.setSeconds(0,0);
      break;
    case 'hour' :
      date.setMinutes(0,0,0);
      break;
    case 'day' :
      date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      break;
    case 'week' :
      roundTimePeriod(date, 'day');
      date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());
      break;
    // month, year ...
  }
  return date
}

['minute','hour','week'].forEach(function(grain){
  console.log(grain + ' ' + roundTimePeriod(new Date(), grain).toString());
});
```

Comment: This might in fact be one of the very few valid use cases for a fallthrough (with the order of cases reversed), so that you don't have to pass multiple zeroes everywhere (or even use recursion, wow).